# File/function that is executed when I open node from view

Tags: views, rules, users

I have created view for displaying the nodes. I want to know which function/file is executed when I click on the node listed in the view table. I want to add some code to the file when the node information is loading. Can anyone suggest me the function/file where i'm supposed to do the changes?

Comment: Your question is too vague to answer. Drupal goes through a whole bootstrap process with a lot of code executing in order to process the request. You can hook into nodes loading via [hook_node_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_load/7). please never ever alter any existing code that is not your own. You need to always hook into code in your own module or overridden theme. Explain what you are trying to achieve in greater detail and perhaps someone can assist you.

Comment: Please don't ask duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

You've two ways to afford the problem:
**Site building way**
If you're using a wiew of rendered nodes (usualy teasers) you can redefine the layout, tags, fields, etc. on admin/structure/types/manage/YOURCONTENTYPE/display/teaser

If you need more options try display suite and fences modules:
https://www.drupal.org/project/ds
https://www.drupal.org/project/fences

**Developer way**
Editing your view, on the "advanced" colum, "other section" you've the "templates" there the "Theme: Information" item.
There you've the name of the templates the view is using.
You can redefine then on your custom them.

**EXTRA BALL: Common sense way**
Probably a mix of two others are que best option